# Vigenere Cipher

Tags: java

This code asks the user to enter a message containing the lower case characters a-z, it then encrypts it into a Vigenere Cipher and also decrypts the cipher to prove the reverse lookup works.

```
package com.testing;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * A Vigenere Square or Vigenere table consists of the alphabet written out 26
 * times in different rows, each alphabet shifted cyclically to the left
 * compared to the previous alphabet, corresponding to the 26 possible Caesar
 * ciphers, At different points in the encryption process, the cipher uses a
 * different alphabet from one of the rows. The alphabet used at each point
 * depends on a repeating keyword.
 */
final class VigenereSquare {

    /**
     * A 2D char array representing the shifted alphabets.
     */
    public static final char[][] SQUARE = fillSquare();

    private static final int LETTERS_IN_ALPHABET = 26;
    private static final int ASCII_RANGE = 256;

    private VigenereSquare() {}

    /**
     * Fill square with shifted alphabets in ASCII positions:
     *  'a' = 97 .. 'z' = 122
     * @return initialised char[][]
     */
    private static char[][] fillSquare() {
        char[][] square = new char[ASCII_RANGE][ASCII_RANGE];
        int start = 'a';
        int end = start + (LETTERS_IN_ALPHABET - 1);
        int index = start;
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            for (int j = start; j <= end; j++) {
                //Check index position if beyond the range of the alphabet
                //reset index position to start.
                if (index > end) {
                    index = start;
                }
                square[i][j] = (char) index;
                index++;
            }
            index = i + 1;
        }
        return square;
    }
}

/**
 * The person sending the message to be encrypted (eg. attackatdawn) chooses a
 * keyword and repeats it until it matches the length of the plaintext, for
 * example, the keyword lemon, the cipher key will be lemonlemonle.
 */
class CipherKey {

    /**
     * CipherKey String value.
     */
    public final String KEY;

    public CipherKey(String text, String keyword) {
        KEY = createKey(text, keyword);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a key string of the same length of the text based on
     * the keyword.
     * @param text to be encrypted
     * @param keyword the chosen keyword
     * @return the key string
     */
    private String createKey(final String text, final String keyword) {
        StringBuilder key = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0, keywordIndex = 0; i < text.length(); i++,
                keywordIndex++) {
            if (keywordIndex >= keyword.length()) {
                keywordIndex = 0;
            }
            key.append(keyword.charAt(keywordIndex));
        }
        return key.toString();
    }
}

/**
 * Using a VigenereSquare and a CipherKey each row starts with a key letter. The
 * remainder of the row holds the letters A to Z (in shifted order). Although
 * there are 26 key rows shown, you will only use as many keys (different
 * alphabets) as there are unique letters in the key string, here just 5 keys,
 * {L, E, M, O, N}. For successive letters of the message, we are going to take
 * successive letters of the key string, and encipher each message letter
 * using its corresponding key row. Choose the next letter of the key, go along
 * that row to find the column heading that matches the message character; the
 * letter at the intersection of [key-row, msg-col] is the enciphered letter.
 * 
 * For example, the first letter of the plaintext, A, is paired with L, the
 * first letter of the key. So use row L and column A of the Vigenere square,
 * namely L. Similarly, for the second letter of the plaintext, the second
 * letter of the key is used; the letter at row E and column T is X. The rest
 * of the plaintext is enciphered in a similar fashion.
 * 
 * Plaintext: ATTACKATDAWN
 * Key: LEMONLEMONLE
 * Ciphertext: LXFOPVEFRNHR
 */
final class VigenereCipherEncrypter {

    private VigenereCipherEncrypter() {}

    /**
     * Encrypt the message using the provided CipherKey and VigenereSquare.
     * @param message to be encrypted
     * @param key used to encrypt message
     * @return encrypted message string
     */
    public static String encrypt(final String message, final CipherKey key) {
        StringBuilder cipher = new StringBuilder();
        String k = key.KEY;
        char[][] square = VigenereSquare.SQUARE;
        for (int i = 0; i < k.length(); i++) {
            //Use the integer values of the key and message char at postion i
            //to determine which character to use from the VigenereSquare and
            //append it to the cipher text.
            cipher.append(square[k.charAt(i)][message.charAt(i)]);
        }
        return cipher.toString();
    }
}

/**
 * Using ciphered text, a CipherKey and a VigenereSquare the
 * VigenereCipherDecrypter achieves decryption by going to the row in the table
 * corresponding to the key, finding the position of the ciphertext letter in
 * this row, and then using the column's label as the plaintext. For example,
 * in row L (from LEMON), the ciphertext L appears in column A, which is the
 * first plaintext letter. Next we go to row E (from LEMON), locate the
 * ciphertext X which is found in column T, this T is the second plaintext
 * letter.
 */
final class VigenereCipherDecrypter {

    private VigenereCipherDecrypter() {}

    /**
     * Decrypt the cipher text using the provided CipherKey and
     * VigenereSquare.
     * @param cipher text.
     * @param key used to decrypt the cipher text.
     * @return decrypted message.
     */
    public static String decrypt(final String cipher, final CipherKey key) {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        String k = key.KEY;
        char[][] square = VigenereSquare.SQUARE;
        for (int i = 0; i < k.length(); i++) {
            int rowIndex = k.charAt(i);
            char[] row = square[rowIndex];
            int colIndex = new String(row).indexOf(cipher.charAt(i));
            message.append((char) colIndex);
        }
        return message.toString();
    }
}

/**
 * This program asks the user to enter a message to encrypt and a keyword. Based
 * on these it will then use a CipherKey and a VigenereSquare. These are then
 * used to encrypt the message using a VigenereCipherEncrypter.
 *
 * Decryption is also performed using a VigenereCipherDecrypter.
 */
public class Vigenere {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter message to encrypt (a-z characters only): ");
        String message = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the keyword: ");
        String keyword = in.nextLine();

        CipherKey cipherKey = new CipherKey(message, keyword);

        String cipherText = VigenereCipherEncrypter.encrypt(message, cipherKey);
        System.out.println("Encrypted message: " + cipherText);

        String decryptedMessage = VigenereCipherDecrypter.decrypt(cipherText,
                cipherKey);
        System.out.println("Decrypted message: " + decryptedMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Say what you mean

> ```
>         int start = 'a';
>         int end = start + (LETTERS_IN_ALPHABET - 1);
>         int index = start;
>         for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
>             for (int j = start; j <= end; j++) {
>                 //Check index position if beyond the range of the alphabet
>                 //reset index position to start.
>                 if (index > end) {
>                     index = start;
>                 }
>                 square[i][j] = (char) index;
>                 index++;
>             }
>             index = i + 1;
>         }
> ```

The purpose of this code seems to be to fill in the section of of the square corresponding to the letters in the alphabet.  The `start` of the alphabet is always defined as `'a'`, but you calculate the `end` from the `start` and `LETTERS_IN_ALPHABET`.  You then use both `start` and `end` as constants.  Why not just make them constants and do away with `LETTERS_IN_ALPHABET`?

```
    private static final char ALPHABET_START = 'a';
    private static final char ALPHABET_END = 'z';
```

Then we can just use those:

```
        for (int i = ALPHABET_START; i <= ALPHABET_END; i++) {
            char c = (char) i;
            for (int j = ALPHABET_START; j <= ALPHABET_END; j++) {
                if (c > ALPHABET_END) {
                    c = ALPHABET_START;
                }

                square[i][j] = c;
                c++;
            }
        }
```

This is more flexible than the original, as we can alter both the start and end via the constants.

Also note that `index` is not actually an index.  It's a letter, so either call it `letter` or something like `c`.

Since our new `c` variable is never used outside the `i` loop and is reset each iteration, simply define it inside the loop.  Moving it from the end to the beginning means that we no longer need to set it to `i + 1`, as the beginning is after `i` is incremented.  During the first iteration of the loop, `c` is set to `ALPHABET_START`, just as it was in the original code.

We also change `c` to be a `char` rather than an `int`, as that allows it to be directly used in the assignment to `square[i][j]` at the cost only of a cast outside the `j` loop.

The comment is now unnecessary, as the code reads like the comment did.  If `c` is past the end of the alphabet, reset `c` to the start of the alphabet.

Consider giving an example, e.g.

```
 * For an ALPHABET_START of 'a' and an ALPHABET_END of 'c', generate 
 * abc
 * bca
 * cab
```

Then it's easier to see that the progression is intentional and not accidental.

### Say what you mean, again

> ```
>         StringBuilder key = new StringBuilder();
>         for (int i = 0, keywordIndex = 0; i < text.length(); i++,
>                 keywordIndex++) {
>             if (keywordIndex >= keyword.length()) {
>                 keywordIndex = 0;
>             }
>             key.append(keyword.charAt(keywordIndex));
>         }
> ```

The first thing to do here is to give the `StringBuilder` an initial capacity.  We know the length, so tell the code.

```
        StringBuilder key = new StringBuilder(text.length());
```

This allows the compiler to allocate the correct length of `StringBuilder` at the beginning rather than picking an arbitrary length and expanding it as necessary.

This code is written similarly to how the previous code was written, but it does something different.  What it's doing is appending `keyword` to `key` until it's the same length as `text`.  So just do that.

```
        final int fullCount = text.length() / keyword.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < fullCount; i++) {
            key.append(keyword);
        }

        final int remainingLength = text.length() % keyword.length();
        key.append(keyword.substring(0, remainingLength));
```

Rather than appending character by character, we append whole copies of the string.  This saves the problem of maintaining `keywordIndex`.

### Multiple files

In Java, it's standard to put each class in its own file.  This makes it easier to reuse classes, as you can copy just the files that you need.

### Testing

I tested this code with your test case and a couple others:

> abc
>   de
>
> abcd
>   ef
>
> abc
>   gfed

It returns the same results as your code for the first case and your test case.  I didn't check the others against your code, as I thought of them after I made modifications.  They all produce reasonable output and echo the original string.

This is an argument in favor of published unit tests.  If you had already been testing a number of circumstances like this, I could have just used your tests.  Then I'd be reasonably sure that both versions did the same thing.  That makes it easier to make modifications with confidence that they won't cause regressions.

Note:  I'm not commenting on this method of encryption.  Good?  Bad?  I'm not the right person to say.  My comments are mainly aimed at readability with a slight nod to performance.